# Unable to locate package ros-melodic-humanoid-nav-msgs

Tags: ros

I am using Ubuntu 18.4. I want to install package ros-melodic-humanoid-nav-msgs but I have an error with Unable to locate package ros-melodic-humanoid-nav-msgs. Can I know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be `humanoid-nav-msgs` does not available via apt. You can download and keep inside `~/catkin_ws/src/`(assume this is your ros workspace) folder and compile with other packages which need `humanoid-nav-msgs`.

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
git clone https://github.com/ahornung/humanoid_msgs.git
cd ../
catkin_make
```